# Searching for an early, highly theoretical, even philosophical, math paper on models or small-world networks

Tags: graph-theory, mathematical-philosophy, mathematical-modeling, paper-request, network-theory

All I can remember is that it was very **high-level / abstact and kind of philosophical**, explaining **(the discovery or interdependence of) small world networks**. I assume that it was **+50 years old** and 'might' be an iconic paper, but maybe not - surely it was by far not as popular as the, already mentioned, paper "small world networks and their dynamics" by Duncan J. Watts & Steven H. Strogatz, but also it was on a completely different level of math.

I think I found it once on [Azimuth](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/) Blog from John Carlos Baez. But it is very large and I don't even find "small world network" in the search (it might have also been mentioned by someone in the comment section).

Comment: 'Theoretical' pretty much describes all of pure mathematics, so I guess you mean it here more or less as a synonym for 'philosophical', or perhaps for 'speculative'?

Comment: That is true, 'theoretical' is not well suited. Let's say, 'very high-level, abstract' mathematics. Like proof theory or universal algorithms.

Comment: I replaced the model-theory tag with mathematical-modeling. Model theory is a branch of mathematical logic, which doesn't actually have anything to do with mathematical models in the applied math sense.

Comment: Surely this is an intersting point, but could you elaborate? The title of the paper is "On models and modelling" and I would say, it is not applied.. (well it was released in an applied mathematics journal xD)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stanley Milgram, [The Small World Problem](http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs224w-readings/milgram67smallworld.pdf), Psychology Today **2**, 60 (1967)

seems to fit the bill: +50 years old, "kind of philosophical", and yes, iconic -- cited more than 9,000 times. There are a few related papers in that time frame, listed [here,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation#Small_world) but the paper from Psychology Today had the largest impact.

Comment: Oh, a Milgram paper. Thank you very much for this! (Unfortunately it's not the one I am looking for)

Comment: I answered my question below, but I'll mark your answer as correct, for being a very valueable addition ;)

Answer (score 4):

I am answering my own question, because I actually did find it again (after 5 years and many tries).
It was not even close to being iconic nor +50y (it just looked old) nor specific on small networks :)

> Rosen, R. (1993). On models and modeling. Applied mathematics and computation, 56(2-3), 359-372. [PDF](http://www.esalq.usp.br/departamentos/leb/aulas/lce164/modelos_modelagem.pdf)

Thanks @Carlo Beenakker for bringing up the Milgram paper!